# Create Core Data. Day and Time separated

Tags: swift, core-data, xcode11.3

I am new with Core Data. I have a project with an Entity called Content and two Attributes: dateCreated with Type Date and text1 Type String. I Create data in Core Data:

```
   func createData(){
       guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
       let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
       let contentEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Content", in: managedContext)!

       let content = NSManagedObject(entity: contentEntity, insertInto: managedContext)
       content.setValue(Date(), forKey: "dateCreated")
       content.setValue("some text", forKey: "text1")

       do {
           try managedContext.save()
       } catch let error as NSError {
           print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
       }
   }
```

With Date() it introduces a timestamp of date and time. Something like: 2020-03-06 09:49:47 +0000

How to introduce day and time separated into two different Attributes?:
Day 2020-03-06
Time 09:49:47

I could find the date:

```
let date = Date() // 2020-03-01 17:29:42 +0000
let calendar = Calendar.current

let day = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
let month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
let year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)
let avui = "\(year)-\(month)-\(day)"
```

But I have many doubts:
- Should I introduce day in Core Data with the Type Date, Type String?
- What Type should I use for the time?
- Is that the right "format" for Core Data:
Day 2020-03-06
Time 09:49:47
- There is a default option for date-time: .xdatamodeld > Inspector > Default Date. I suppose that there is no possibilities of a Default if I want date and time separated. Is that right?

Comment: I don’t you should do that, extract the time in swift code instead when you need it

Comment: What is the reason for two attributes one for date and one for time? Reasons could be easy grouping or sorting separately by date and time or queries about time of day, weekday, ... . It depends on use cases how to store date and time values separately and what attribute data type then should be used. About the question: _There is a default option for date-time ... Is that right?_ Answer: There is a default option for any attribute, it depends on the type how the default value looks like.

Comment: @Marcus: 1- The reason: The user wants to sort by date. Time is not relevant for them. 2- I said that I know there is a default for date-time. My question is for a default for date and another for time.